# kie-maven-plugin for Gradle Drools 6.4

Tags: drools

We are developing a Drools application and our organization has standardized on Gradle. We need to use the kie-maven-plugin to create and compile our rules in a KJar. This is so we can hot swap new versions of the rules. Is there a Gradle version of this plugin available? I don’t think that Maven plugins can be used in Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to port, I think its this project: https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/kie-maven-plugin

However there is a way of doing drools as resource files like here: https://github.com/Spantree/drools-examples/
and this line is what got me stuck: https://github.com/Spantree/drools-examples/blob/master/src/test/groovy/net/spantree/examples/drools/helloworld/HelloWorldSpec.groovy#L19
(They just get the session directly from container, ignoring getting a base first)

This does not give you the compile time checks the maven module gives you.
However hot swapping resource based drools should be easier (I think).